# When a table in SQL Server has a large-ish nvarchar (say nvarchar(2000)) when the row is stored in the page, do all 4000 bytes get stored?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-performance

I'm adapting an audit scheme from this: https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database which calls for creating an audit table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Audit
(
AuditID [int]IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Type char(1), 
TableName varchar(128), 
PrimaryKeyField varchar(1000), 
PrimaryKeyValue varchar(1000), 
FieldName varchar(128), 
OldValue varchar(1000), 
NewValue varchar(1000), 
UpdateDate datetime DEFAULT (GetDate()), 
UserNamevarchar(128)
)
```

I want to ensure that I'm storing as little as possible for each row that is inserted into the `Audit` table. In my case, I can shorten the width of `TableName`, `PrimaryKeyField`, `PrimaryKeyValue` and `FieldName` because I know the actual max lengths of those things. I have one particular table that has a particular column defined as nvarchar(2000), so if I stay with this generic approach I'll need to use nvarchar(2000) for `OldValue` and `NewValue`.

I was wondering about SQL Server's internal optimizations regarding storage space actually used in a page. When a row is stored with long varchars or nvarchars, is the full defined length actually used to store the row in a page, or does SQL Server only store the actual bytes used. For example, if only `Hello!` is stored in `OldValue` above, how many bytes will the `OldValue` actually occupy in the page for such a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [**`nvarchar(N)`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql) it would be `2 + (2*N)` maximum bytes stored in row for this value. The first 2 are the length, and then 2 bytes per unicode character actually stored in the row. This is the maximum space occupied.

If your unicode string is only 15 characters then it would be 32 bytes (even as an `nvarchar(2000)` datatype).

I would also recommend using `sysname` for names of system objects for forward (and backward) compatibility in your scripts.

You also might be interested in this audit script: [Quick And Easy Audit Tables - Dave Britten](http://dave.brittens.org/blog/quick-and-easy-audit-tables.html)

Comment: Thanks, SqlZim, for the quick reply! So why does SQL Server bother with `nvarchar(N)`? I understand the difference between in-page storage for `nvarchar(N)` where N <= 4000 vs  large object storage for `nvarchar(max)`, but why not have just nvarchar(4000) and `nvarchar(max)` to keep things simple? Are there some additional optimizations internal to SQL Server that make, say, `nvarchar(100)` more efficient than `nvarchar(4000)`?

Comment: `nvarchar(max)` is handled differently, and even as a variable can have significant impact on performance, as it supports up to 2gb of data. Using a smaller maximum (N) for `nvarchar()` would have an impact on calculations for estimating memory grants. There is also index key width to be considered as well: [Maximum Size of Index Keys](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> When a row is stored with long varchars or nvarchars, is the full defined length actually used to store the row in a page, or does SQL Server only store the actual bytes used

Even though ,you define a variable length column ,SQL will use the storage space for only the values that are declared..

This has been covered here :[How are varchar values stored in a SQL Server database?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5705203/2975396)

Below is the relevant part taken from answer of Martin Smith

> All varchar data is stored at the end of the row in a variable length section (or in offrow pages if it can't fit in row). The amount of space it consumes in that section (and whether or not it ends up off row) is entirely dependant upon the length of the actual data not the column declaration

Below is a sample demo to prove the same

```
create table dbo.test1

(
fixedlencol varchar(400),
varlengthcol varchar(max),
var_len_Nvarcahrcol nvarchar(max)
)

insert into dbo.test1
values
('a','abc','def')
```

Now if use DBCC PAGE and DBCC IND following the example from here:Inside the Storage Engine: [Using DBCC PAGE and DBCC IND to find out if page splits ever roll back](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-using-dbcc-page-and-dbcc-ind-to-find-out-if-page-splits-ever-roll-back/)

below is the output,i got for first row insert

> Slot 0 Column 1 Offset 0xf **Length 1** Length (physical) 1
>
> fixedlencol = a
>
> varlengthcol = [BLOB Inline Data] Slot 0 Column 2 Offset 0x10 **Length 3** Length (physical) 3
>
> varlengthcol = 0x616263
>
> var_len_Nvarcahrcol = [BLOB Inline Data] Slot 0 Column 3 Offset 0x13 **Length 6** Length (physical) 6

Reason for last column taking double bytes than actual length is due to Nvarchar..